Package installation error - libgl1-mesa-glx in Ubuntu 24.04
Is "libgl1-mesa-glx" integrated into the new Ubuntu 24.04 release? I get the following error message when trying to install this package.
$ sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx' has no installation candidate

See Issues installing libgl1-mesa-glx in particular this answer
